# Are pure HTML and CSS questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, site-recommendation, doctype

If an HTML and CSS question has no JavaScript or other programming language related question, is it on topic? I read on earlier posts that these questions belong on DocType, but it was closed February 2013.

Since HTML is a markup language, not a programming language, do these kinds of questions belong on Stack Overflow, or Webmasters, or is there another site specifically for HTML/CSS?

Comment: Do you have a link to the closed question? I'm curious to see what question would have been closed, when dealing with the subjects you mention.

Comment: The DocType site, which Stack Overflow promoted, was closed http://doctype.com/

Comment: Ah, sorry. I misread. I thought you were referring to a question on SO.

Comment: @scrblnrd3: Doctype is not owned or operated by Stack Exchange (the people who run Stack Overflow). They are merely mutual affiliates whom once advertised each other. Doctype has absolutely no bearing on the on-topicness of HTML and CSS questions here.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

HTML and CSS are part and parcel of web development, and by extension programming web applications.

As such, questions about both technologies are on topic for Stack Overflow, as evidenced both by the tags [css](/questions/tagged/css) and [html](/questions/tagged/html) existing (with different version variants) and questions that contain HTML/CSS and no JavaScript or server side programming.

As far as we are concerned, HTML or CSS *are* source code - they are part of the source code of the web.

In short - such questions (so long as they are not simple typos) have a place on Stack Overflow and are certainly on topic.

Comment: I sense a Good Answer badge coming soon ;) +1

Comment: I guess this is the official line, but I suspect there are a lot of people who would disagree. In my view, if it doesn't have a branch (ie, an if-statement), its not a program.

Comment: @TylerDurden - In the context of a web application? If someone asks about tab order in a UI, there is no mention of `if`s. Is that also off-topic in your opinion?

Comment: [so] has [windows] tag. That doesn't mean questions about how to use Windows is on-topic on [so]. Bad point.

Comment: @user202729, but the Windows tag specifically mentions: "*Note: GENERAL WINDOWS SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC.*", so that might not be the best example as well.