# Answers that are purely a redirect to doctype.com

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers, not-an-answer, doctype

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4056868) answer in the low quality review today:

> I recommend you post Your question here: http://doctype.com

it's been deleted now, but it seems there are [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539328/what-are-some-best-css-practices-do-you-re-use-previous-css-how-about-framewor/2539353#2539353) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347366/div-at-bottom-of-window-and-adaptable-height-div/1347374#1347374) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493945/2-divs-position/1493953#1493953) that are basically the same thing.  Some of them even have upvotes!

Now, it looks like we [used to have some sort of partnership with that site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67217/194698), but after checking it out, it looks like **they closed down about a year ago** (as shown by the banner on their main page, which links to [more details here](http://blog.doctype.com/doctype_is_closing_on_the_14th_1). This was even referenced in [another meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182978/194698) a while ago.

> We're sad to say that after almost 4 years we've decided to close Doctype. We will stop accepting new content on the 14th of February.
>
> Our worlds have changed a lot over that time and it's been hard to find the time to keep Doctype as up to date as we'd have liked. In that time, the pace of development on StackOverflow and the StackExchange network has lead to their dominance. There's no way we have the time to keep Doctype up to the standard they are setting.

Go StackOverflow! We are setting the standard!

Anyways, where was I? Oh yeah... So these "answers" that are just a redirect to doctype.com - they should be cleaned up.

I had started flagging them as "Not an Answer" (since they aren't - at most by today's standard they're a comment), since I don't have the power to do much else, but this seems rather inefficient way of dealing with it.

One of the users who provided an answer like this [implied via comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2519653/836214)) that it should these just be left alone as they were "valid at the time of writing".  This doesn't feel right to me, as time changes the "usefulness" of an answer. I downvoted some (as the answers are definitely "not useful" by today's standards) but stopped that as well when I realized how many of them there were... Which brings me to meta to ask this question:

**What should be done to these answers? Flags? Downvotes? Deletion (by someone with powers)? Other?**

Comment: I'd go for Search and Destroy by someone who wields the nukehammer.

Comment: Most of the flags I raised on this are still "active", though one has now been declined with this comment: "flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention". Am I misunderstanding the purpose of flags entirely, or can this be clarified somehow?

Comment: @Chris that likely means the handling mod felt that this post was something that the community could address without involving a diamond. You could try flagging again with VLQ; you've obviously seen how that queue can deal with such answers. I've flagged the one remaining non-deleted answer you've linked to and we'll see how that turns out.

Comment: If you do a search for "doctype.com", you'll find a lot more of them... I didn't think flagging as "Not an Answer" specifically required a moderator to look at it (vs "the community") - don't high rep users have similar powers? Most of the other flags on these questions were marked useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with you on this point, there are a lot of "legacy" answers out there and this needs to be addressed.

The thought that they were "valid at the time of writing", I get it, especially if you are overly sensitive to your rep numbers, but that they were valid, one, two, three years ago **doesn't help anyone now** especially if the previously valid answer is either

1. Incorrect by today's standards
2. Gone, in the case of outside link answers
3. Was barely an answer to begin with

I think it is valid to comment first and give the original author a chance to update their answers, then flag and then finally bump the answer if they have no value **today**. I have had a few of my old answers questioned or people simply ask for updates through comments, and I have no problem trying my best to do that.

The value in the questions and answers on this site are **how it can help today**.

Comment: Well, this sounds like what I'll be doing - out of the 6 questions I originally went through before posting this question, 5 of the answers have now been deleted (and flags marked as helpful), and only one declined ([the post still exists](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2519653/836214), though arguably, this one is specifically asking for resources in the question...). I look at this as positive feedback for this approach, and will continue applying it to other answers that are just a link to doctype.com.

Comment: And on the bright side, most of the rest of the results were just a reference mixed in with some other content.